# MS Remote Desktop client has difficulty playing back audio

Tags: windows-10, audio, remote-desktop

I use RDP to access a remote work machine of my company. It works well in all aspects but playing back audio. Specifically coming from calls/conferences from messengers such as MS Teams or Zoom, usual sounds like notifications do not give me any trouble as far as I can tell. What happens is that the session appears to freeze or literally choke on audio. The screen no longer updates in real time and I hear garbled audio and seldom proper sounds, and the whole audio output is delayed, while there is active audio playback.

Normally I use the official Remote Desktop client from the Windows store, and it's the one that has this issue. Accidentally I remembered before I switched over to it that I have been using MSTSC and it didn't exhibit any strange issues with sound. As I just checked it's still true. This is a bummer, as I really can't stand using the remote machine fullscreen as the latter client does it. Why does one client has this issue while another from the same vendor doesn't is beyond me.

Is there anything I can do to make the store client not to choke on audio like that? The local machine is fully updated Windows 10 Home, the remote is Windows 10 Pro.

I have tried turning off the UDP protocol using the registry, but it made the issues even worse, it almost completely locks up the session until there is no audio.

Comment: A remote session is not suitable for audio/video streaming. It may work, and it may not. It will introduce latency and is bandwith consuming. My advise is always to do this outside of the server environment and only do it locally.

Comment: See, I understand. But it's not the culprit that I did something inherently broken. One RDP client has little trouble with doing this, another chokes on it. I want neither to do that, and clearly there is something that allows the former to work correctly that hopefully may make the other also work properly.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it may or may not work. Streaming audio/video was never intended to be used on RDP and newer clients use compression and other stuff to make the experience more fluid but also break things like streaming audio/video. Long answer short, its not possible with the new client, and its a miracle it worked on the old. The best I can think of, is finding another third-party client where it works well enough.